# Trying to enter recovery mode on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

I am trying to enter recovery mode. I first enter the grub menu and click 'c' on the kernel (recovery mode) line. After this I set=prefix and set=root to the correct settings. Then I insmod  normal --> insmod linux ---. linux /vmlinuz file ---. initrd /initrd.file. Then I type in boot but for some reason it boots me into initramsfs(BusyBox). Once in initramfs I type in exit to see the error message I am getting. It prints "Warning: Type of root file system is unknown, so skipping check. mount: mounting on /root failed; No such file or directory. Failed to mount as root file system.

Running the command "mount" shows rootfs on /type rootfs.
I'm not sure where to start my troubleshooting as I don't have much experience with this so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Either your pointed the kernel to the wrong root filesystem ( with the root= command line argument ), or your root filesystem is trashed.  Also there is no need to insmod normal and run the normal command -- you're already in normal mode.  Also why did you edit the command instead of just pressing enter?

Comment: I pointed the kernel to the fileystem that has the initrd and vmlinuz files. The reason I edit is because if i straight into recovery mode it gets stuck on a kernel panic. I think like you said my root filesystem may be trashed.

Comment: No, you pointed *grub* there, not the kernel ( and grub already knew that ).  You need to have a root= argument on the linux line to tell the kernel where the root fs is.  Also if grub could read the root fs ( assuming you don't have a separate /boot fs ) then your fs probably isn't trashed.

Comment: I used both the "set root=" and "set prefix=" commands and pointed them to the correct filesystem but the issue is the same. The boot up gets stuck on a kernel panic error "cant mount root filesystem" so maybe I am not doing it correctly

Comment: Again, those are telling *grub* where it can find the kernel and its modules.  To tell the *kernel* where the root filesystem is, you have to add a root= argument to the *linux* command.

Comment: Ohh ok sorry about that. I missed what you were saying in your previous command. I ran the linux root=/vmlinuxfilename and it gave an error of "invalid file name". The file does exist for sure as it shows up when I ls the filesystem.

Comment: No, the argument to root= needs to be the device where your root filesystem is, for instance, /dev/sda1.